# QtGui.QComboBox and setStyleSheet- I need that only the selected value will jave a different BG color

Tags: combobox, pyqt4, stylesheet

I'm using setStyleSheetin order to set colors to my QtGui.QComboBox.
I need that a specific selected value will cause the area of the selected field to have a red BG color, but, the list itself should remain with white bg color.
I was able to create 2 different cases and both have problems, please advice.

First case+problem:
I managed to change selected value bg color to red, but, at the moment user clicks in someplace else on the UI, the bg color is white again:

```
self.ComboBox.setStyleSheet("selection-background-color:red;")
#At the moment user clicks somewhere else, the bg is white again. and this is     problematic for me.
```

Second case+problem:

```
self.ComboBox.setStyleSheet("background-color:red;")') 
#This option causes the whole list to become red, but it remains red as needed and does not turn to bg=white if I click in someplace else in the UI.
```

Thank you in advanced for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try QSS objects roles -- ie,

QSS

`ComboBox::item:selected 
{
  background-color: red;
}`

Comment: thanks for reply, but, if I understand you right, it same as I already did:  "selection-background-color:red;" - and this is not good enough as explained above.
Please advice... thank you.